# Unit Test vs Integration Test in Web Development

Tags: java, php, unit-testing, tdd, integration-testing

I would like to ask about using Unit Testing in Web Development. The idea of Unit Testing is great but does it really bring value in the context of web application? Second part of my question is about TDD. If one creates an integration test before the actual code can this approach be called "Test Driven Development"?

**1. Assumptions**

By the definition Unit Test should test code on only one service layer. If a test tests code across multiple layers we have an integration test.

**2. Argument**

**2.1 No Algorithms**

There are not many algorithms in a Web Application. It's not like building a 3D Physics engine where every method does something challenging and hard to debug. Web application is mostly about integration and generating HTML.

The biggest challenges for a web application are: 
- clean code (universal problem for any software but not testable)
- data consistency
- integration (Programming Language, File System, Configuration Files, Web Server, Caching Systems, Database, Search Engine, External APIs - all those systems have to work together at a request)

If you want to build a Unit Test for every class in a web app you will be testing (in most cases): filling arrays, string concatenations and languages' native functions.

**2.2 Cost**

Just because a Web App is all about integration there are always multiple dependencies. You have to mock many different classes and writing even a small test might be actually a big job. What's even worse it's not only about test. Software needs to be testable. It means that one has to be able to inject dependencies in almost every class. It's not always possible to inject dependencies without creating additional layer between two classes (or systems). It complicates code and makes it more expensive to work with.

**3. Integration Test**

If web development is all about integration why not to test it? There are few counter arguments.

**3.1 Integration test says "something is broken" but doesn't say where**

That really comes down to: How much time does it take to find a bug when an integration test fails in comparison to time required for making code "UnitTestable" and more complicated (I guess this is subjective)? In my experience it never took long to find source of a problem.

**3.2 You can run unit test on any environment, it's hard to do with an integration test**

Yes, if you want to run integration test without a database. Usually there is a database. So long you operate on fix data and clean after each test then it should be fine. Transactional databases are perfect for this task. Open transaction, insert data, test, rollback.

**3.3 Integration Tests are hard to maintain**

I can't comment on that because all my test work well and I never had problem with that.

**4. Create good Unit Tests!**

The whole argument can be attacked with "If you create your Unit Test right, then you don't have any problems.". Can't that be the same with integration tests? If it's easier to create an integration test why not to stick with it and just make it right?

Don't get me wrong I'm not against Unit Test. It's perfect idea and I recommend to everybody. I'm trying to understand: does it really fit web development? I would like to hear you opinions and experience.

Comment: ***"2.1 No Alghorithms"*** - That greatly depends on the app now, doesn't it? Just because it lives on the web doesn't automatically mean it's not complex or contains no complex algorithms.

Comment: @deceze Absolutely! But generally speaking a web app doesn't have that many of them.

Comment: Maybe you should take a look at [ATDD](http://janetgregory.blogspot.com/2010/08/atdd-vs-bdd-vs-specification-by-example.html) which basically solves your problem. [Growing Object-Oriented Software, Guided by Tests](http://www.amazon.com/Growing-Object-Oriented-Software-Guided-Tests/dp/0321503627) introduces the idea of never working on a feature before writing a failing acceptance test for it. Pluralsight.com has a course about Test First Development. Check out  [part 2](http://pluralsight.com/training/Courses/TableOfContents/test-first-development-2) of the course about ATDD.

Comment: @Songo Thank you for this, I'm definitely going to look into that. Just for clarification I don't have a problem per say. I'm trying to understand all prose and cones. If Unit Test is always the way to go let it be.

Answer (score 5):

This is a *damn* good question, and one that **more developers should be asking themselves**.

I don't think this only applies to web development, but I think it's a good example to base the discussion on.

When deciding on your testing strategies, the points you raised are very valid.
In a commercial world, cost (in terms of time) is likely the most important factor.
I always follow some simple rules to keep my testing strategies realistic.

- Unit test important, unit testable "libs" (Auth, Billing, Service Abstractions, etc)
- Unit test models, assuming you have any, where possible (and it really should be possible!)
- Integration test important endpoints of your application (totally depends on the app)

Once you've got these three points nailed, given your cost constraints you could potentially continue to test anything else that makes sense, in the way that makes sense.

Unit testing and integration testing aren't mutually exclusive, and unless you're building a beautifully unit testable library, you should do both.

Answer (score 3):

The short answer is yes. Unit tests are valuable as are integration tests.
Personally I'm not that good at doing TDD, but what I've noticed is that it greatly improves design because I have to think first and then code.
That's invaluable, at least, for me but it also takes a lot of getting used to.
This, I think, is the main reason to why it is so widely misunderstood.

Let's go through your points:

**No Algorithms (but what you mean is few):**

Well as stated in the comments, that depends on the application. This actually has nothing to do with TDD. Having few algorithms is not an argument to not test them. You may have several different cases with lots of different states. Wouldn't it be nice to know that they work as intended?

**Cost**

Sure it will cost, and if it is a small project, you might not get any value from TDD if you or your developers are new to it. Then again a small project might be just the thing to get started with it, so you are up to speed for the next, bigger project. This is a calculation you must do yourself. We are programmers, not economists.

**Integration Test**

Test that too!

**Integration test says "something is broken" but doesn't say where**

I'm sorry but I don't understand this one.

**Hard to maintain**

If it is hard to maintain you're doing it wrong. Write the test first, change the test before the implementation, when changing the code. Failing tests during development is a must for TDD. *Actually don't quote me on that one, that is just my limited understanding of TDD.*

I find [this](http://thecuttingledge.com/?p=144) to be a very nice quote about unit-tests

> Unit tests should be prescriptive, not descriptive. In other words, unit tests should define what your code is supposed to do, not illustrate after the fact what your code does.

What it boils down to is that integration tests and unit testing are two different things. TDD is a methodology for development, integration tests is more a validation of the application working as expected from a users vantage point.

**Edit**
The community wiki says this about integration testing:

> In an integration test, all input modules are modules that have
>   already been unit tested. These modules are grouped in larger
>   aggregates and integration tests (defined in an integration test plan)
>   are applied to those aggregates. After a successful integration test,
>   the integrated system is ready for system testing.

So actually my understanding of what `integration testing` is was wrong from the start, but I don't think my answer is too far off except for the last paragraph.

Comment: Thank you for your time and the answer. You make valid points.

Answer (score 0):

Integration test takes more time to execute compared to unit test.

"...all about integration there are always multiple dependencies" -> if you are coding on a dependent unit without completing the others, then you can't do integration test yet.  If you want to make sure your code is working at this point, you you can do unit testing.

If each members of your team is developing their own dependent unit, they can't do integration test yet because the required units are still being developed by others.  But at least they can make sure their code is working if they perform unit testing before committing to repository.

Comment: Thank you for your input. Speed of integration test hasn't been an issue so far. Most of them run reasonably quick.